# network ping issues, computer not pinging anything in network and trying to ping itself

Tags: dhcp

When trying to ping anything in the local network the computer tries to ping itself and says destination host unavailable

```
C:\Users\3aaa>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.127: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.127: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.127: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.127: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

It wonst find the network printer either.

I am using Windows 7 Home.

the results from ipconfig/all are:

```
C:\Users\3aaa>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 3aaa-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home.gateway

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home.gateway
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802
I-E NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-29-AF-13-E8-AB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.127(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 18 November 2015 10:28:23
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 19 November 2015 11:13:44
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-76-1C-22-C6-74
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.home.gateway:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home.gateway
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

the arp -a is
C:\Users\3aaa>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.127 --- 0xf
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           00-1e-67-e7-27-2b     dynamic
  192.168.1.20          5c-93-a2-fd-1b-5d     dynamic
  192.168.1.106         e4-98-d1-47-ae-54     dynamic
  192.168.1.111         74-29-af-0b-55-8b     dynamic
  192.168.1.118         74-e2-8c-e3-bb-d8     dynamic
  192.168.1.200         5c-93-a2-fd-1b-5d     dynamic
  192.168.1.254         60-03-47-09-e0-17     dynamic
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  226.178.217.5         01-00-5e-32-d9-05     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

 c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc
```

Thanks

any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include 1/ your operating system 2/ the output from `ipconfig /all` (assuming windows) and 3/ the contents of your `hosts` file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

Comment: also `arp -a` would be handy to see.

Comment: thanks for the update! So, first thing I noticed is you were trying to ping 192.168.1.1.   What device/computer do you expect to be at 192.168.1.1?  It looks like your gateway/dhcp server (which is going to be your router) seems to be at 192.168.1.254.   Were you trying to ping your router or some other device that has 192.168.1.1?   What happens when you ping 192.168.1.254?

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is the server which is on the same network. When i ping the router I receive 4 replies. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not trying to ping itself, it is trying to ping `192.168.1.1` as per your request. The problem is that it cannot reach `192.168.1.1`, and therefore gives you the response of whichever host discovered the problem. In your case, this host is your own computer.

It's not a fault, it's information to use for further troubleshooting. If the amount of network hops was bigger and the problem was further down the line, you would get a similar message from the last host you could reach.

Based on your ipconfig output I can see that your gateway is set to `192.168.1.254`. Try pinging that instead to see if your network works as intended (presuming that your gateway is working as intended).

Comment: Ok thanks but the user is not able to connect to the network printer and i believe that is linked with this issue? Any advice?

Comment: @JoshShanker Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Pinging 192.168.1.254 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.254: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
I do receive replies from pinging the router
Ping statistics for 192.168.1.254:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 8ms

Comment: So your computer is on the network, but whatever you're pinging on `192.168.1.1` is not

Comment: but i can ping everything on the network from 192.168.1.1?